# How to use the comparison test with a series whose terms are given by a rational function?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

What is the proper way to find $B_n$ using the comparison test, do I have to compare $A_n$ to the largest term on the numerator/denominator?

> Ex. $A_n:\sum\frac n{n^2-1}$ diverges.

If I compare $A_n:\sum\frac n{n^2-1}$ to $B_n = 1 / n^2$ then $A_n > B_n$ 
which means if $B_n$ diverges then $A_n$ will diverge (Does not Diverge)?

If I compare $A_n:\sum\frac n{n^2-1}$ to $B_n = n / n^2$ then $A_n > B_n$
which means if $B_n$ diverges then $A_n$ will diverge (correct as $B_n$ diverges)

If the proper method is to take highest term on numerator / denominator of $A_n$ to use as $B_n$ then why do I often see solutions where this is not the case?

Ex. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hpF3wqiPHQU

Ex. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SzE01kHg3Yo

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: There is no trick, except to use inequalities. If you increase the denominator, you get something smaller. So adding 1 to the denominator gives a smaller sequence. You could also subtract one from the numerator, factor and cancel, and get the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the **direct comparison test** you want to first determine whether or not you think the series converges.

If you think the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n$ converges, then try to find a $B_n$ such that $B_n \ge A_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} B_n$ converges.  The idea is that the "larger" series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} B_n$ converges, therefore so should the "smaller" series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n$.

If instead you think the series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n$ diverges, then try to find a $B_n$ such that $B_n \le A_n$ for all sufficiently large $n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} B_n$ diverges.  The idea is that the "smaller" series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} B_n$ diverges, therefore so should the "larger" series $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n$.

In this case, since $A_n = \dfrac n{n^2-1}$, you can choose $B_n = \dfrac1n$, because
$$ n^2 - 1 < n^2 \iff \frac1n < \frac{n}{n^2-1}$$
for all $n > 1$.  Therefore $B_n < A_n$ for all $n > 1$.  Then since $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} B_n$ diverges (it's the harmonic series), we know that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n$ must also diverge.

---

For the **limit comparison test** your method for choosing $B_n$ is correct in your second case - choose $B_n$ to be what $A_n$ will "behave like" as $n$ gets very large.  If $A_n = \dfrac n{n^2-1}$, then as $n$ gets very large, the $-1$ contributes nothing relevant, so $A_n$ will "behave like" $\dfrac n{n^2}$ for very large $n$.  So you would choose your $B_n$ to be $B_n = \dfrac n{n^2} = \dfrac1n$, and since $\lim_{n \to +\infty} \frac{A_n}{B_n} = 1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} B_n$ both converge or they both diverge.  Well, we already know that $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} B_n$ diverges because it's the harmonic series.  Therefore $\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} A_n$ diverges as well.

---

Note:  These two comparison tests will not work on alternating series.

---

> If the proper method is to take highest term on numerator / denominator of An to use as Bn then why do I often see solutions where this is not the case?

If by "highest term" you mean "highest-order term" or "term with the highest degree" then that really only applies to functions whose numerator and denominator are polynomials (or at least algebraic functions with real powers of $n$).  What you really want to think about is what $A_n$ "behaves like" as $n$ gets really large, as explained above, **but remember that this is only how you want to choose $B_n$ for the limit comparison test, not the direct comparison test**.  Both videos you linked to are doing the direct comparison test.

Comment: Lets say I chose An = n/n^2 - 1 to compare to Bn = 1/n^2 which is also An > Bn
But 1/n^2 converges?

Comment: @mathguy $A_n > B_n$ and $\sum B_n$ converging tell you nothing about $\sum A_n$.  If $A_n > B_n \ge 0$ then $\sum A_n > \sum B_n$.  Just because the smaller series converges, it doesn't mean that the larger one does also.  In general, if $A_n \ge B_n \ge 0$ for all sufficiently large $n$ and if $\sum B_n$ converges, then $\sum A_n$ could converge or it could diverge.  The test would be inconclusive at this point and a different $B_n$ would be needed or, more likely, a different test entirely would be needed.

Comment: understood, tyvm